# Combining DictVectorizer in one model using sklearn and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
vectorizer = DictVectorizer()
feature_vectorstest = vectorizer.fit_transform(train['tokens'].apply(featurize))
feature_vectorstest2 = vectorizer.fit_transform(train['tokens'].apply(featurize2my))

combined_features = FeatureUnion([('Dicvectorizer',feature_vectorstest),('DicVect',feature_vectorstest2)])
combined_features.transform(train['tokens'])
```

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'' // in line combined_features.

If both 'feature_vectorstest' and 'feature_vectorstest2' contains word 'sad', then feature would be 'feature_vectorstest_name_sad' and 'feature_vectorstest2_name_sad'.